# C# Step Into variable list

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, mode, step-into

There usually is a variable list at the bottom of the screen that helps me follow the value of different variables in my app while using the f11 'step into' function, but since I updated to web developer 2012 I can't seem to find this list. Was it removed? or is there a way to open it? thanks!

Comment: Actually it might be the `Debug` => `Windows` sub menu

Answer (score 3):

Set a break point in the project, start debugging your application, once you hit the break point, go to Visual web developer, Under Deubg-> Windows, see if you find `Locals` option. That will show the local variables during debugging.

Comment: @HtusaAdssad, you are welcome, I see that you haven't accepted any answer to your questions. Please see [How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)